# How do you sort a CollectionViewSource by one property, then by another as a tiebreak?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently, my CollectionViewSource sorts a collection of items by description. If the description is the same, I want to sort based on ID. How can I specify to sort by description first, then by ID?

I've tried adding a second SortDescription with PropertyName="Id", but that hasn't worked.

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding Items}" >
 <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
 <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description"/>
 </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
 </CollectionViewSource>
```

**EDIT:** The ID property was private on the viewmodel. No errors thrown.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6469303/56778

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm not sure why adding the `SortDescription` for `Id` does not work as it should work fine.

Like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Items}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
 </CollectionViewSource>
```

I put together a full example of this working as you want:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="124" Width="464" Name="UI" >
<Window.Resources>

   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Items}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
   </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> myVar = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "Stack", Id = 5 });
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "OverFlow", Id = 1 });
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "StackOverFlow", Id = 2 });
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "Stack", Id = 1 });
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "Stack", Id = 0 });
        Items.Add(new MyObject { Description = "OverFlow", Id = 7 });  
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Items
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
}


public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Desc: {0}, Id: {1}", Description, Id);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Worth noting here that the myVar collection needs to be instantiated before the InitializeComponents is called.

Answer (score 2):

@sa_ddam213's answer should work, but you don't need the extra ToString()method; all you need to add to your XAML is to turn **IsLiveFilteringRequested** on, at least as in the .Net Framework 4.5.1.

```
<CollectionViewSource IsLiveFilteringRequested="True" x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Items}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a list of enums that had to be converted and then ordered. My code ended up looking like this with the help of the other answers.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyEnumList" Source="{Binding ListFromViewModel, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumConverter}}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="."/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>                
</CollectionViewSource>
```