# How to order properties within an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I have a class that looks like the model below, such that there are several integer properties `Cand1Votes` , `Cand2Votes` and `Cand3Votes` that needs to be displayed in `DescendingOrder` in the view for each `Election` object. For a particular election, `Cand1Votes` may be first while `Cand3Votes` second and `Cand2Votes` third.

My solution so far is to create a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int?>>` for each of the election objects then send that to the ViewModel and use that in the View.

My solution so far *works*, but I'm looking for a solution whereby I can dynamically order the integer elements within the object, without having to create another `List<KeyValuePair<string, int?>>`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Model

```
public class Elections{
    public int Id           { get; set; }
    public int? TotalVotes  { get; set; }
    public int? Cand1Votes  { get; set; }
    public string Cand2Name { get; set; }
    public int? Cand2Votes  { get; set; }
    public string Cand2Name { get; set; }
    public string Cand3Name { get; set; }
    public int? Cand3Votes  { get; set; }
    public int? OtherVotes  { get; set; }
}

 public static List<KeyValuePair<string, int?>> OrderByVotes(Election election)
 {
     var votesArray = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int?>>()
     {
         new KeyValuePair<string, int?>(election.Cand1Name, election.Cand1Votes),
         new KeyValuePair<string, int?>(election.Cand2Name, election.Cand2Votes),
         new KeyValuePair<string, int?>(election.Cand3Name, election.Cand3Votes),
         new KeyValuePair<string, int?>("Other Candidates", election.OtherVotes)
     };
     var result = votesArray.OrderByDescending(k => k.Value);
     return result.ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Drive-by downvoter, care for a reason?

Comment: I would expect the candidates to be in an observable collection, not having them as separate variables. Than you can set this collection as the collection source of your view, and sort it in the view, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992072/how-do-you-sort-a-collectionviewsource-by-one-property-then-by-another-as-a-tie

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this model represents a database table, but correct me if I'm wrong. It _would_ be easier to take the advice of @AmittaiShapira, but if that isn't an option what exactly do you mean by re-ordering within the object? Do you want `Cand1Name` and `Cand1Votes` to contain the lowest vote name/value, `Cand2Name` and `Cand2Votes` to contain the next lowest value, and so on?

Comment: @Sam I never even thought about that. But that is another possible way I could do it. My initial thought was to dynamically print out Candidate Name and Votes in descending order.

Comment: In that case if you can re-factor like suggested in Matt's answer you'll make life much easier on yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think a little refactoring on the model will make this a bit easier:

```
public class Election
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TotalVotes { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }

    public void AddCandidate(Candidate c)
    {
        Candidates.Add(c);
    }

    public List<Candidates> SortCandidates()
    {
        return Candidates.OrderByDescending(k => k.NumVotes).ToList();
    }
}

public class Candidate
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int NumVotes { get; set; }        
}
```

This will allow any number of candidates to be in your Election class, and you can call the SortCandidates() method on an Election object to get a List of Candidates sorted by descending NumVotes.  Foreach thru that list of candidates on your view to display the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc place candidates in order.