# Showing multiple headers in one column with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to have more than one property in a column like the following:

[image: DataGrid with more than one header in a column.]

Now, it's easy to create a cell template to show more than one property, but how would one go about creating a header template that shows more than one property that still lets you sort by clicking on them? So you should be able to sort by *first name* just by clicking on `First Name` header, and same goes for all the other properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469303/sort-on-multiple-columns-in-wpf-datagrid may be it will be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two `TextBlock`. In `Tag` property you should transfer name of the property from your data class. This string from `Tag` property you will use to set `SortMemberPath`. In the event `MouseLeftButtonDown` you can get from `Tag` property name of the actual sort property and assign it to `SortMemberPath`.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,52">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="First Name" Tag="FirstName" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Tag="LastName" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" />                                
                    </Grid>        
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock s = sender as TextBlock;
    string sortPath = s.Tag as string;
    dataGrid1.Columns[0].SortMemberPath = sortPath;
}
```

You can also add `TextBlock` style if you want to show which property is currently sorting property and bold it font.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="First Name" Tag="FirstName" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Columns[0].SortMemberPath, ElementName=dataGrid1}">
                                <DataTrigger.Value>
                                    <sys:String>FirstName</sys:String>
                                </DataTrigger.Value>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </DataTrigger>                             
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Tag="LastName" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Columns[0].SortMemberPath, ElementName=dataGrid1}">
                                <DataTrigger.Value>
                                    <sys:String>LastName</sys:String>
                                </DataTrigger.Value>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>        
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Where `sys` is following namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example of StringFormat](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/):

And change the header of your DataGrid column like the example below :

```
 <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
               <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{1}{0}{2}">
                        <Binding Source="{x:Static sys:Environment.NewLine}"/>
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
```

with `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`