# WPF - DataGrid: custom sort with a computed result

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid shown a DataView with some values, sales figures for example, like

id | name | sales 
15 | Smith | 100 
16 | Mueller | 150 
17 | Andrews | 75

And in this DataView is also a single row with sums like
0 | total | 325

Is it possible to integrate a custom sort (by click on columnHeader), but to have the sum row everytime as first row? In sql I achieve this with something like that: ORDER BY IF(id = 0, 0, 1), [columnName]. Can I get this in a DataGrid too? I didn't find out how. Thx ...

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I add a computed column to my table:

```
tabView.Table.Columns.Add("_sort", typeof(int));
tabView.Table.Columns["_sort"].Expression = "iif(id = 0, 0, 1)";
```

And the sorting event on a click on the columnheader looks like

```
private static void Grid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = ((DataGrid)sender);
    var cView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource);

    //Alternate between ascending/descending if the same column is clicked 
    var direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    if (cView.SortDescriptions.Count >= 2 && cView.SortDescriptions[1].PropertyName == e.Column.SortMemberPath)
        direction = cView.SortDescriptions[1].Direction == ListSortDirection.Descending ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

    cView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    cView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("_sort", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    grid.Columns.First(c => c.SortMemberPath == "_sort").SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    cView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, direction));
    grid.Columns.First(c => c.SortMemberPath == e.Column.SortMemberPath).SortDirection = direction;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[thx to this helpful entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469303/sort-on-multiple-columns-in-wpf-datagrid)